# transactions failing everytime i make a transaction on https://test.payu.in/_payment_options

Tags: payment-gateway, payumoney

Im using test credentials in my code.
$MERCHANT_KEY = "gtKFFx";
$SALT = "eCwWELxi";

Test Card Name: any name
Test Card Number: 5123456789012346
Test CVV: 123
Test Expiry: Dec 2017

but all the transactions are getting failed and im being redirected  to the failure page.

Comment: Have you found any solution regarding this problem. Please let me know, i am facing the same issue

Comment: yup use these details  Card number : 5123456789012346  cvv: 123  name: test  expdate 05/20 @ShubhamSaini

Comment: Thanks @DesmondDias this works with the credentials you've provided. although any cvv is causing the transaction to be successful.

Comment: 000 makes the transaction failed also any date other than 05/20

Answer (score 2):

Using below details I have successfully complete payment

> Card number : 5123456789012346
>   CVV : 123
>   Name : test
>   Expiry Date : 05/2020

Comment: Expire date is expired

Comment: @giveJob you can use any future expiration date like 05/21 and it will work on test mode

Comment: transaction reaches till OTP and then fails on clicking Pay! is there any specific test OTP to be given?